# Sequence Notation(Product Notation)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone explain how to do the steps to solve this please? I'm lost!

Sequence $z$ defined by $z_n= 2n-1$, $n\geq 1$.

$\prod_{i=3}^6 z_i$

Answer (score 2):

$$\prod_{i=3}^6 z_i = z_3 z_4 z_5 z_6 = (6-1)(8-1)(10-1)(12-1) = 5 \times 7 \times 9 \times 11\\= 35 \times 99 = 35 \times (100-1) = 3500 - 35 = 3465$$

Basically $\prod_{i=a}^{b} f(i)$ means $f(a) \times f(a+1) \times \cdots \times f(b-1) \times f(b)$.

Comment: ok i get it now thanks that was very clear!